# Solving KKT equations with implicit function in sympy

Tags: python, optimization, sympy

I am new to SymPy and want to solve the KKT equations to the following optimization problem:

\begin{align*}
&\max_{L_A, L_C,X_a, X_{na}, s, u} U(L_A, L_C, X_a, X_{na})=(\hat{\imath}-L_C)(X_a-S_a)^{\alpha_a}(X_{na}-S_{na})^{\alpha_{na}}(I-\hat{\imath}-L_A)^{\alpha_{A}}(\hat{\imath}-L_C)^{\alpha_C}\
s.t.\quad& p_a X_a + p_{na} X_{na} + p_A (I-\hat{\imath}-L_A)+p_C (\hat{\imath}-L_C) = Y = p_a f(L,\theta,K)-p_A L_A - p_C L_C+p_A(I-\hat{\imath})+p_C(\hat{\imath})
\end{align*}

The constraint has an implicit function in it (by that I mean that the actual form of $f(L,\theta,K)$ is unknown). By assumption, this function is positive monotonic and concave, that is
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}>0 \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}>0 \quad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial L^2}<0 \quad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial L \partial \theta}>0.$$

To complicate things, input $L$ to function $f(L,\theta, K)$ is given an explicit form because it involves four of the six choice variables:

$$L(L_C, L_A, u, s) = L_A - s u L_C + s v(u) L_C + (1-s) v_0 L_C$$

where v(u) is again positive monotone and concave.

Below is my attempt at implementing this in SymPy. I get an error at the solving stage (at the end) which I believe to be a result of SymPy not knowing how to take the derivative of an implicit function ($f(\cdot)$) w.r.t another function ($L(\cdot)$) that is itself defined.

How can I tell SymPy that $f(\cdot)$ is supposed to be positive monotone and concave?

Any ideas how to proceed would be appreciated.

```
    # import stuff
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import Function
from sympy.solvers import solve
import sympy as sp

# define the maximization variables
X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u = sp.var('X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, L_C, L_A, s, u', positive=True);

# import exogenous variables

a1 = sp.symbols('alpha_1') # alphas
a2 = sp.symbols('alpha_2')
a3 = sp.symbols('alpha_3')
a4 = sp.symbols('alpha_4')

S1 = sp.symbols('S_1') # Subsistence levels
S2 = sp.symbols('S_2')
S3 = sp.symbols('S_3')
S4 = sp.symbols('S_4')

v0 = sp.symbols('v_0') # raw skill level

i = sp.symbols('\hat{\imath}') # children in the household - time endowment
I = sp.symbols('I') # household size and total time endowment

p1 = sp.symbols('p_1') # price vector
p2 = sp.symbols('p_2')
p3 = sp.symbols('p_3')
p4 = sp.symbols('p_4')

climate = sp.symbols('theta') # climate variable
capital = sp.symbols('K') # quasi fixed land and (non-human) capital

lam = sp.symbols('\lambda') # shadow prices (lagrange multiplier)

# technology of skill enhancement
v = Function('v')(u)

# labour equivalence function (cases 1 and 2)
L1 = Function('L_1')(u, s, LA, LC)
L1 = LA-s * u * LC + s * v * LC + (1 - s) * v0 * LC
L2 = Function('L_2')(u, LA, LC)
L2 = v * (LA/u)+v0*(LC-LA/u)

# define production function
f1 = Function('f')(L1, capital,climate) # positive monotonic and convex in L1, capital, and climate
f2 = Function('f')(L2,capital, climate)

# utility function (cases 1 and 2)
U1 = Function ('U_1')(X1, X2, LA, LC)
U2 = Function ('U_2')(X1, X2, LA, LC)
U1 = (i-LC) * (X1-S1)**a1 *(X2-S2)**a2 * (I-i-LA-S3)**a3 * (i-LC-S4)**a4 
U2 =          (X1-S1)**a1 *(X2-S2)**a2 * (I-i-LA-S3)**a3 * (i-LC-S4)**a4

# main constraints
#G1 = Function('G_1')(X1, X2, LA, LC, f1)
G1 = p1*X1 + p2*X2 + p3*I - p3*i -p3*LA + p4*i - p4*LC - p1*f1 + p3*LA + p4*LC - p3*I-p3*i - p4*i
#G1 = Function('G_1')(X1, X2, LA, LC, f2)
G2 = p1*X1 + p2*X2 + p3*I - p3*i -p3*LA + p4*i - p4*LC - p1*f2 + p3*LA + p4*LC - p3*I-p3*i - p4*i

# Lagrangians
Lagrange1 = U1 - lam * G1 # case 1
Lagrange2 = U2 - lam * G1 # case 2
Lagrange3 = U1 - lam * G2 # case 3
Lagrange4 = U2 - lam * G2 # case 4

# Calculate KKT-conditions
grad1 = [sp.diff(Lagrange1,c) for c in [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u]] # gradient of Lagrangian w.r.t choice variables
KKT1 = grad1 + [G1]

grad2 = [sp.diff(Lagrange2,c) for c in [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u]] # gradient of Lagrangian w.r.t choice variables
KKT2 = grad2 + [G1]

grad3 = [sp.diff(Lagrange3,c) for c in [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u]] # gradient of Lagrangian w.r.t choice variables
KKT3 = grad3 + [G2]

grad4 = [sp.diff(Lagrange4,c) for c in [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u]] # gradient of Lagrangian w.r.t choice variables
KKT4 = grad4 + [G2]

### Here the thing breaks down - perhaps because the convexity of f1 is not specified.
########################################################################################################
candidates1 = sp.solve(KKT1, [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u, lam], dict=True) # solve the KKT equations #
candidates2 = sp.solve(KKT2, [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u, lam], dict=True) # solve the KKT equations #
candidates3 = sp.solve(KKT3, [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u, lam], dict=True) # solve the KKT equations #
candidates4 = sp.solve(KKT4, [X1, X2, X3, X4, LC, LA, s, u, lam], dict=True) # solve the KKT equations #
########################################################################################################


# return candidates for optima
print(candidates)
´´´
```

Comment: Your unknowns are in undefined functions e.g. you want to solve for `u` but your equations involve both `u` and `v(u)` where `v` is an undefined function. It's impossible for `solve` to handle that without knowing what `v` is hence the error `could not solve \lambda*(-L_C*u - L_C*v_0 + L_C*v(u))`

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Benjamin, yes that is what I thought it was. Is there a way to solve this by giving ```solve``` some assumptions about the function's curverture rather than an entire definition? I mean, it could potentially be solved by pen and paper that way, but I really dread doing it manually with that many symbols.

Comment: What assumptions about curvature would make it possible to invert `v(u)-u = a` to get u in terms of `a`? How would you do that on pen and paper?

Comment: My understanding was that if, by assumption, v(u) and f(K,L,theta)  were monotone and concave, I can at least make qualitative statements about their derivatives involved (i.e. they are positive). In this exercise I am only interested in these directional statements and so that would be enough.

Comment: You are not asking solve for a qualitative statement. You are asking it for an explicit expression for the solution and it can not give you one - knowing about convexity does not help with that. You will need to find a different approach.